# PHP - unset a value from Iterator

Tags: php, iterator, unset

I have a filter iterator. How can a unset a give value in it. I have tried unset($list[$key]), but that gives me an error : Cannot use object of type `Filter as array`

Comment: Show us the code you tried.

Answer (score 2):

The documentation states that the [`FilterIterator`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.filteriterator.php) "filters out unwanted values", and the logic behind that is in the [`accept()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/filteriterator.accept.php) method which you must implement.

So you don't *unset* anything, you just reject (or not accept, technically) values you don't want.

```php
class DoctorFilter extends FilterIterator
{
    public function accept(): bool
    {
        $obj = $this->getInnerIterator()->current();
        
        return is_string($obj) && str_starts_with($obj, 'Dr.');
    }
}

$people = [
    'Dr. Jekyll',
    'Mr. Hyde', // This item will be removed
    'Dr. Frankenstein',
];

foreach (new DoctorFilter(new ArrayIterator($people)) as $item) {
    echo $item.PHP_EOL;
}

/*
Outputs:

Dr. Jekyll
Dr. Frankenstein
*/
```

Demo: https://3v4l.org/ieTAP#v8.2.6